# Execute PHP on button press

Tags: php, html

I'm new with PHP and I started that program to try PHP. The program works fine. However, I want to start the php script while a button is pressed. When I click the button it do not work.

Do someone know why?

Can you explain me how it works?

Thanks.

```
<?php
if($_POST["act"]){
     $start_time = microtime(true);

     $random1 = rand(1,200);
     $random2 = rand(1,200);
     $random3 = rand(1,200);
     $random4 = rand(1,200);

     while ((($random1!=$random3) || ($random1!=$random2) || ($random1!=$random4))) 
     {
                $random1 = rand(1,200);
                $random2 = rand(1,200);
                $random3 = rand(1,200);
                $random4 = rand(1,200);
     }
     $end_time = microtime(true);
     $execution_time = ($end_time - $start_time);
     
     echo "<br>Execution time of script = ".$execution_time." sec";

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>EX1</title>
</head>
<body>
        <from method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="act">
                <button type="submit">Run the script!</button>
        </from>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<form method="post" action="your_file.php">` should work... i guess:)

Comment: This should work per se; but creating output _before_ the HTML doctype already, is not such a good idea. Move that PHP block somewhere into the body.

Comment: Okay correction, this should work, once you spell `form` correctly.

Comment: `from` != `form`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 0):

change the HTML tag `<from>` to `<form>` then try again. It should work!

```
<form method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="act">
     <button type="submit">Run the script!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: OMG Sorry, what a FAIL.

Answer (score 0):

change the HTML tag `<from>` to `<form>`, also you forgot to pass a value on the hidden field. make sure to make the hidden field like  `<input type="hidden" name="act" value="hello">`. This means you are passing a value, which is caught by the `$_POST['act']`. If you trigger this without a value then, the PHP script will not be executed.

Please run the solution below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>EX1</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="act" value="hello">
                <button type="submit">Run the script!</button>
        </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php


if($_POST['act']){
     $start_time = microtime(true);

     $random1 = rand(1,200);
     $random2 = rand(1,200);
     $random3 = rand(1,200);
     $random4 = rand(1,200);

     while ((($random1!=$random3) || ($random1!=$random2) || ($random1!=$random4))) 
     {
                $random1 = rand(1,200);
                $random2 = rand(1,200);
                $random3 = rand(1,200);
                $random4 = rand(1,200);
     }
     $end_time = microtime(true);
     $execution_time = ($end_time - $start_time);
     
     echo "<br>Execution time of script = ".$execution_time." sec";

}
```